# Increment variable every 5 iteration of for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I'm not 100% sure how to phrase this question, so feel free to change the Question title to something that makes sense.

I have an object `solution` which contains a property name `days` which holds 10 arrays, see an example below

```
{
    "sameShiftHolds": true,
    "sameStaffHolds": true,
    "sameRoomHolds": true,
    "days": [{
        "availableStaff": [
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [4, 8, 7]
        ],
        "availableRooms": [
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [2, 7, 9]
        ],
        "suitableStaff": [
            [22, 44],
            [22, 44],
            [4]
        ],
        "suitableRooms": [
            [89, 23],
            [22, 44],
            [2]
        ],
        "ValidStartDate": true
    }, {
        "availableStaff": [
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [4, 8, 7]
        ],
        "availableRooms": [
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [2, 7, 9]
        ],
        "suitableStaff": [
            [22, 44],
            [22, 44],
            [4]
        ],
        "suitableRooms": [
            [89, 23],
            [22, 44],
            [2]
        ],
        "ValidStartDate": false
    }, {
        "availableStaff": [
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [4, 8, 7]
        ],
        "availableRooms": [
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [2, 7, 9]
        ],
        "suitableStaff": [
            [22, 44],
            [22, 44],
            [4]
        ],
        "suitableRooms": [
            [89, 23],
            [22, 44],
            [2]
        ],
        "ValidStartDate": true
    }, {
        "availableStaff": [
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [4, 8, 7]
        ],
        "availableRooms": [
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [2, 7, 9]
        ],
        "suitableStaff": [
            [22, 44],
            [22, 44],
            [4]
        ],
        "suitableRooms": [
            [89, 23],
            [22, 44],
            [2]
        ],
        "ValidStartDate": true
    }, {
        "availableStaff": [
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [4, 8, 7]
        ],
        "availableRooms": [
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [2, 7, 9]
        ],
        "suitableStaff": [
            [22, 44],
            [22, 44],
            [4]
        ],
        "suitableRooms": [
            [89, 23],
            [22, 44],
            [2]
        ],
        "ValidStartDate": true
    }, {
        "availableStaff": [
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [4, 8, 7]
        ],
        "availableRooms": [
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [2, 7, 9]
        ],
        "suitableStaff": [
            [22, 44],
            [22, 44],
            [4]
        ],
        "suitableRooms": [
            [89, 23],
            [22, 44],
            [2]
        ],
        "ValidStartDate": true
    }, {
        "availableStaff": [
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [4, 8, 7]
        ],
        "availableRooms": [
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [2, 7, 9]
        ],
        "suitableStaff": [
            [22, 44],
            [22, 44],
            [4]
        ],
        "suitableRooms": [
            [89, 23],
            [22, 44],
            [2]
        ],
        "ValidStartDate": true
    }, {
        "availableStaff": [
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [4, 8, 7]
        ],
        "availableRooms": [
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [2, 7, 9]
        ],
        "suitableStaff": [
            [22, 44],
            [22, 44],
            [4]
        ],
        "suitableRooms": [
            [89, 23],
            [22, 44],
            [2]
        ],
        "ValidStartDate": true
    }, {
        "availableStaff": [
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [4, 8, 7]
        ],
        "availableRooms": [
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [2, 7, 9]
        ],
        "suitableStaff": [
            [22, 44],
            [22, 44],
            [4]
        ],
        "suitableRooms": [
            [89, 23],
            [22, 44],
            [2]
        ],
        "ValidStartDate": false
    }, {
        "availableStaff": [
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 22, 44],
            [4, 8, 7]
        ],
        "availableRooms": [
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [3, 6, 77, 89, 23],
            [2, 7, 9]
        ],
        "suitableStaff": [
            [22, 44],
            [22, 44],
            [4]
        ],
        "suitableRooms": [
            [89, 23],
            [22, 44],
            [2]
        ],
        "ValidStartDate": true
    }]
}
```

On my site I have a custom made calendar view of a week, which is created from a template, starting from Monday to Friday. By default, there are 2 weeks but a user can change how many weeks they want to see. Each week is split up by a div with a unique id `"solCol0"`, `"solCol1"` etc....

[image]

I then loop through the number of weeks selected, in this case we have `2`.
And then loop through the length of `solution` which is `10` in this case.
I only want to loop 5 times (for each day of week) and then after 5 loops, increment the columdId by 1 to append the details onto the next week, for example the first 5 loops are appended to `"solCol0"` and then the next 5 are appended to "`solCol1`" and if the user has selected more than 2 weeks, to 3, `solution` length would increase to 15 so the next 5 loops would append to "'solCol2"` etc...

Sorry if this isn't very clear, in general I just have to increment a value after every 5 loops. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
loadSolutionStartRows: function(dates, solution) {
    var self = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        var columnId = "#solCol" + i;
        var startDate = moment(dates[i], 'Do MMM');
        var rowDates = [];
        var iterate = 5;
        for (var d = 0; d < solution.days.length; d++) {
            //Every 5 loops - columnId = "#solCol" + i + 1;
            rowDates.push(moment(startDate).format('ddd (Do MMM)'));
            startDate.add(1, 'days');
            var selectedDate = rowDates[d];

            var statusClass;
            var statusIconClass;
            if (solution.days[d].ValidStartDate === true) {
                statusClass = "sxpTableHeaderIconGreenStatus";
                statusIconClass = "octicon " + "octicon-check";
            }
            if (solution.days[d].ValidStartDate === false) {
                statusClass = "sxpTableHeaderIconRedStatus";
                statusIconClass = "octicon " + "octicon-x";
            }


            $(columnId).append(self.solutionTableRow({
                rowId: i + 1,
                date: selectedDate,
                statusClass: statusClass,
                statusIconClass: statusIconClass,
                trainerCountEarly: 1,
                trainerListEarly: 1,
                roomCountEarly: 1,
                roomListEarly: 1,
                trainerCountLate: 1,
                trainerListLate: 1,
                roomCountLate: 1,
                roomListLate: 1
            }));
        }
    }
}

},
```

With the code above I achieve the image below, it adds 10 days instead of the 5 as I want.

[image]

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i + 5)

Comment: @twothreebrent That would increase the variable by 5 on each round, is not what OP has asked for.

Comment: @twothreebrent This also causes and endless loop for me

Comment: `if (i % 5 === 0) { foo++; }`

Comment: thats my fault I read what he wanted to do wrong.

Comment: You need a variable outside of the scope of your loop that you can increment when the loop variable is a multiple of 5.

Comment: @JaredSmith Can you maybe explain what that code does for a js newbie and where I am supposed to put this line of code, thanks

Comment: @mcclosa done deal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will want to have a variable that gets incremented every 5th iteration, so you need to check if the index is a multiple of 5:

```
var foo = 0;

for (var i; i < someLength; ++i) {
  if (i % 5 === 0) {
    foo++;
  }
}
```

This uses the modulus operator to get the remainder of `i / 5`. If its 0, then we know the index is a multiple of 5.

Note that this is strictly unnecessary, one can alternatively just do

```
Math.floor(someLength / 5);
```

Or more succinctly:

```
someLength / 5 | 0;
```

Both will truncate the result of the division to an integer, and you will know how many 5's `someLength` contains.

Comment: Thanks, this does work, however I think I still need to change my code as I'm still getting 10 days rendering instead of 5 so my page still loads like the last image. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.floor(i/5)`. It just divides `i` by the 5 and then rounds it down.

This will return 1 for values of i from 0 to 4, 1 for values of i from 5 to 9 etc.

In your example:

```
 var columnId = "#solCol" + Math.floor(i/5);
```

Answer (score 0):

For every step of the loop, check whether the iterator is divisible by 5 `if (i % 5 == 0)`. If it is, increment your columnId variable

Answer (score 0):

Like I commented, you need a variable outside of the scope of your for loop that you can increment when the inner loop variable is a multiple of 5. Here is an example of that.

```js
var outerVar = 0;

for (var innerVar = 1; innerVar <= 10; innerVar++) {
  console.log("Iteration " + innerVar + " uses outerVar " + outerVar + ".");
  if (innerVar % 5 === 0) {
    outerVar++;
  }
}
```